# Preg_matching email and looking for specific text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a bunch of emails that I read as text in my program and they all have phone numbers such as these:

```
+370 655 54298
+37065782505
37069788505
865782825
65782825
(686) 51852
```

How would I go about finding them and saving it into a variable?

For now I am doing it like this:

```
$found = preg_match('^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}^', $text, $num);
```

But it does not working at all

Comment: I can't see why you are talking about emails and why you use regex, if you want to save phone number ?

Comment: It works for 3 of them, right? You need to allow for spaces, parenthesis, and less than 9 characters. Something like https://regex101.com/r/IK3P8w/1/ could do it that would match more than phone numbers though. The `+` also doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @yunandtidus I edited the question,I load the emails as simple text.

Comment: `$num` would contain your match, not `$found`, and since using `preg_match` only 1 match will be found.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest stripping out '+','(',')',' ' and testing if it is a ctype_digit

remove all characters and test if numeric, this assumes that the result is a phone no, if you were to run this on an email address the result would be false

```
 var_dump(ctype_digit(str_replace([' ', '+', '(', ')'], '', '(686) 51852')));
```

> **TRUE**

```
 var_dump(ctype_digit(str_replace([' ', '+', '(', ')'], '', 'r@pm.mr')));
```

> **FALSE**

Comment: This will match any character that is not a digit `\D` and replace it with an empty string removing (if there is) the possibility to recognize a phone number by it's structure.

Comment: You could substitute \D with the characters in your phone no '+','(',')',' ' and test the result. Sorry i should have just wrote the regexp. but it seemed like you had a good handle on it. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "[libphonenumber](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php)" Google Library.

There are two functions you may find useful

- isPossibleNumber - quickly guessing whether a number is a possible phonenumber by using only the length information, much faster than a full validation.
- isValidNumber - full validation of a phone number for a region using length and prefix information.

Answer (score 0):

This should work https://regex101.com/r/E2PzRN/2

```
#\+?\(?\d+\)?\s?\d+\s?\d+#

<?php

$regex = '#\+?\(?\d+\)?\s?\d+\s?\d+#';
$x = [
    '+370 655 54298',
    '+37065782505',
    '37069788505',
    '865782825',
    'hjtgfjtdfjtgdfjt',
    '65782825',
    '(686) 51852',    
];

foreach ($x as $y) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $y, $match)) {
        echo $match[0] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Check it in action here https://3v4l.org/6AlQa

Answer (score 0):

We distinguish here 3 types of phone numbers.

The first type is this one:

```
+37065782505
37069788505
865782825
65782825
```

Here, the beginning `+` is optional. we thus consider that we have 7 digits minimum for these numbers.

The regular expression obtained is therefore

```
(\+?[0-9]{7,})
```

The second type is this one:

```
+370 655 54298
```

Here we have a first block consisting of a `+` followed by 2 to 6 digits and then several other blocks of 2 to 6 digits and separated by spaces.

The regular expression obtained is therefore

```
(\+[0-9]{2,6}(\s[0-9]{2,6})+)
```

The last type is this one:

```
(686) 51852
```

This is a first block consisting of 2 to 6 digits surrounded by parentheses and then several other blocks of 2 to 6 digits and separated by spaces.

The regular expression obtained is therefore

```
(\([0-9]{2,6}\)(\s[0-9]{2,6})+)
```

The complete extraction code is therefore

```
preg_match_all("#(\+?[0-9]{7,})|(\+[0-9]{2,6}(\s[0-9]{2,6})+)|(\([0-9]{2,6}\)(\s[0-9]{2,6})+)#",$text,$out);
$found = $out[0];
```

where `$found` is an array.